# PreFilterMessage is not called when hosting C# control within Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-7, activex, imessagefilter

Here is a sample:
1. Create a class 'public class RichTextBoxEx : RichTextBox, IMessageFilter'.
2. Implement 'public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)'.
3. Enter into edit mode of the control and type any text.

The result is as describe above... the 'PreFilterMessage' is not called when the control is hosted within the browser.
Also by giving the FullTrust access to control the PreFilterMessage is not getting called

Comment: I didn't think IMessageFilter classes automatically got added as filters; I've always called Application.AddMessageFilter. Does your message filter work under plain WinForms?

Comment: Wow, just did a search in google for PreFilterMessage, and even though this post only has been made 20 mins ago, it is already in the top 5 of the results :) Btw, totally off topic here :)

Comment: Heh, happened to me the other day - "Ah, here is an answer to your question, and it's on StackOverflow! Hey, wait a minute..."

Comment: Lol, seems to me we are all googling the answers to people's questions... and find it :p Perhaps we should offer all of them a basic course in google ;)

Comment: Yes, I have called Application.AddMessageFilter(passing the IMassageFilter) object but still PreFilterMessage is not getting called when I Hosted the control in IE7

Answer (score 1):

Not all messages are passed through the PreMessageFilter mechanism. Only the messages that are posted to your control are filtered - direct messages are not filtered.

Override the WndProc() function to filter all kinds of messages.